# Dropotron left padding not working

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce that right space on my drop-down menus.

[image]

Tried with:

```
.dropotron li {
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #e6e6e6;
            padding-right: 0 !important;
        }
```

But no sucess. Any ideas?

**MY CSS:**

```
.dropotron {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        background: #fff;
        color: #444;
        min-width: 13em;
        padding: 0.75em;
        margin-top: -0.5em;
        font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0.125em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    }

        .dropotron li {
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #e6e6e6;
            padding-right: 0 !important;
        }

            .dropotron li:first-child {
                box-shadow: none;
            }

        .dropotron a {
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
            letter-spacing: 0.05em;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            display: block;
            line-height: 3em;
            border: 0;
        }

        .dropotron.level-0 {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

            .dropotron.level-0:before {
                content: '';
                border-left: solid 0.5em transparent;
                border-right: solid 0.5em transparent;
                border-bottom: solid 0.5em #fff;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: -0.45em;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -0.25em;
            }
```

**MY HTML:**

```
<li>
 <a href="#" class="submenu fa-angle-down"><a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/flag1_a.png" alt="" /></a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/flag2.png" alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/flag3.png" alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/flag4.png" alt="" /></a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: can you please give me the url of site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a an example to work off of I'm just guessing here but I think it's probably the `min-width: 13em;` on the `.droptotron` class that's controlling the width. Try reducing that and see if it helps.

Comment: You were right. I just removed `min-width: 13em` and all the drop-downs are now adjusting to text width. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Cheers